# What is the purpose of "condition && func()" when used as a statement?

Tags: javascript, syntax, operators

I recently ran across the following [effective] syntactical construct:

```
d <= f && func3();
```

The actual construct is of the form:

```
d > f ? a > b ? func1() : func2() : d <= f && func3();
```

**What is the purpose of this construct?**

My best guess is that `func3` will only be executed if `d <= f` returns falsy because of the short-circuit evaluation in the `&&` operator, but I don't think that makes sense given that the logic in the actual function would prevent `d <= f` from ever being false at that point in the code, and **it's clear from DOM-watching that `func3` is being executed**.

If you want to see the whole code, I found this in http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=9358063bfb40 as referenced by https://stackoverflow.com/faq in the `moveScroller` function (full function below, it's in the line that has `d <= f && j.css({...})` to reset back to a relative position).

```
function moveScroller() {
    var g = $("#scroller").width(),
        d = function () {
            var d = $(window).scrollTop(),
                f = $("#scroller-anchor").offset().top,
                j = $("#scroller");
            d > f ? j.height() > $(window).height() ? j.css({
                position: "fixed",
                top: "",
                bottom: "0px",
                width: g
            }) : j.css({
                position: "fixed",
                top: "0px",
                bottom: "",
                width: g
            }) : d <= f && j.css({
                position: "relative",
                top: "",
                bottom: ""
            })
        };
    $(window).scroll(d).resize(d);
    d()
}
```

Comment: Anyone who writes code that makes you sit there and scratch your head should be smacked.

Comment: This is almost worth posting to DailyWTF.

Comment: Maybe it's to deal with the possibility that "d" and "f" are both `NaN` :-)

Comment: This looks like the pretty-printed output of a code minifier like Google Closure compiler.   Minifiers often convert `if` statements to `&&`, `||`, and `? :` operations to save space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If either `d` or `f` are non-numeric (`NaN`, non-number strings, etc) then both tests `d > f` and `d <= f` can return `false`.

So in the code

```
d > f ? a > b ? func1() : func2() : d <= f && func3();
```

at first glance it looks like `d <= f` is redundant, but it will short-circuit the execution of `func3` if either `d` or `f` is non-numeric.

Ugly code!

Comment: `<` works perfectly fine with non-number strings.  Given strings, or when the *ToPrimitive* abstract operator applies to both operands produces a non-numeric value, it coerces its operands to strings and compares them lexicographically.  See [11.8.5](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.5)

Comment: @MikeSamuel -- I think I'm missing something in my understanding of [11.8.5](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.5): `n > 9 || n <= 9` returns false if n is `NaN` or a string like `'abc'` -- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkH87/)

Comment: @jsfiddle, Sure, because *ToNumber* `('abc')` is NaN.  Perhaps I misunderstood your post because I missed the "either ... or".  Should I have interpreted "**either** `d` or `f` are non-numeric" to exclude the case where both are non-numeric as in `"abc" > "bcd" || "abc" <= "bcd"`?

Answer (score 3):

As you surmised, it means almost the same thing as

```
if (var1 <= var2) someFunction();
```

It doesn't mean *exactly* the same thing; the `if` statement is, well, a statement, while that `&&` construct is just an expression (and so might be part of a larger expression).

*edit* — I do agree now that because that code is in the "else" wing of the `?:` operator that "d" has to be less than or equal to "f". Perhaps it was written that way to clarify things, but I have the feeling that the author of that code wan't much interested in clarity.

Answer (score 2):

It's basically hacking the boolean && operator. People sometimes use `&&` and `||` operators as shortcuts for conditions. This is possible, because of the behaviour of these operators:

- && will check second operand only when first operand is true, e.g. `true && thisWillAlwaysBeExecuted()` and `false && thisWillNeverBeExecuted`
- || operator will check second operand only when first operand is false, e.g. `true || thisWillNeverBeExecuted()` and `false || thisWillAlwaysBeExecuted()`

I think it's a bad practice because it hides the intent. What that expression means is: "compare these two operands" and the intent is "if certain condition is met - perform this task". I really doubt that there's any gain in performance, and the argument "it's less characters" stopped working when the first IDE was invented.

Answer (score 1):

```
d > f ? a > b ? func1() : func2() : d <= f && func3();
```

Is `d` more than `f`? If true then

```
a > b ? func1() : func2()
```

Is `a > b`? If true then run `func1()`. If not true then run `func2()`.

If `d` was not more than `f`, then

```
d <= f && func3();
```

if `d` is less than or equal to `f`, run `func3()`

*Edit*

As to the purpose of using the `&&` it is usually done when you want to avoid doing the later part of the conditional statement, and essentially break, if the condition prior to the `&&` was false. Usually these are used to make sure that a property which does not exist is not accessed by testing for it or for a feature which guarantees its existence.

Comment: Right, and I think the question is, why bother to compare "d" to "f" *again*, since if you get to that point it must be the case that "d" is not greater than "f".

Comment: @Pointy - I cannot guess as to the why of some logic I see here :) Just trying to write out the series of conditional statements.